# Do I have to create both getter and setter for a field?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have a class like this :

```
class Product {
  int id;

  Product([this.id]);
}
```

And I allow my product id to be changed. So, am I good with above or should I use below model

```
class Product {
  String _id;

  Product([this._id]);

  set id(id) => _id = id; // setter

  get id => _id; // getter
}
```

Comment: you can use a private setter and public getter and vise versa, to set private getter / setter, you need to add a _ in front of the field, in your case since you already use _id as your private veriable, you will have to change it to something like _idValue. otherwise you may encounter an error

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use of you class, for instance if the class is a model class for instance
(Employee class)which is only used to save some data and no functionality, 
then it should include a setter and getter for its member variables. 
But if there is service layer class, which uses Employee class and performs certain operations on it, then use of setter and getter is not a must.

Answer (score 1):

Getters and setters are created automatically for non-private class instance variables. So your top code is fine for reading and updating the id variable from anywhere.